# What's the best symbol to use to mask unknown digits?

Tags: numbers, hidden, special-characters

I'm working with groups of product identifiers and need to be able to represent when the last couple numbers of the identifier are unspecified.

For example, a product might have the following product IDs:

```
1000-1234-01
1000-1234-05
1000-1234-10
1000-1234-50
```

I would like to represent this group with just the first eight digits, and use a masking character to indicate that the IDs are actually 10-digits long but the user doesn't need to worry about the last two digits, for example using `X` characters:

```
1000-1234-XX
```

But I'm concerned the `X` character may not be universally recognized as a "placeholder" character. They might confused the `X` as *part of the ID*. (My users are in the US, but I can't assume their cultural background).

Other options I can think of:

- Elipsis: `1000-1234-…`
- Underscore: `1000-1234-__`
- Times: `1000-1234-××`
- Whitespace: `1000-1234-`
- Question marks: `1000-1234-??`
- Asterisks: `1000-1234-**`
- Bullets: `1000-1234-••`

The masking character is less ambiguous when users will recognize the format of the number, e.g., for credit card numbers `XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-4000` or phone numbers `(555) 123-XXXX`, but is more critical when you want to avoid ambiguity.

What is the best character to use in this case?

Comment: when you say 'unspecified', is there a task the user needs to do here? Is there a cost to the user for it being unspecified? Just looking for more context to possibly rethink my answer based on how I interpret the post.

Comment: The task is analogous to “Please choose your model number”. The last 2 digits represents the color of the product, but we don't care about the colors so we just display a list of model numbers excluding the color digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, go with the most common pattern users are likely to encounter outside your application.

**Asterisks** are quite common. You'll see them in password recovery, banking applications and the like.

- Elipsis can be confusing, as the dots don't hint how many characters are being masked. It's not 1 for 1.
- Underscores can blend together, looking like several characters, or one wide one
- Question marks give the implication that the system is *missing* the data
- Whitespace can give the impression that the system has *failed to load the data, or it's missing*

Comment: Asterisks are traditionally used to indicate "wildcards" or unknowns in search strings. This is probably why they're commonly used to denote unknown values elsewhere.

Comment: Asterisks seem like a good choice. I wish there was a big version of asterisks because they can just look like dots in some fonts at small sizes. Oh, there are some! Alternate asterisks in unicode: the FULLWIDTH ASTERISK `＊` might be useful, and if a large one is needed there is the HEAVY ASTERISK `✱`, and of course how could I not mention the HEAVY EIGHT TEARDROP-SPOKED PROPELLER ASTERISK `❋` 